# scala automatic scroll down on ScrollPane Component

Tags: scala, user-interface, scroll, scrollpane

So I have a TextArea inside of a scrollPane, the text area is scrollable but I'd like it to be always at the bottom of the scroll bar so I see the latest contents.. Is it possible on Scala?
here's what I have so far:

```
        val messages= new TextField(22,44){     
               editable = false
        }
        val frame = new MainFrame{            
            title="testScrollBar"
            contents = new FlowPanel{
               val outputTextScrollPane = new ScrollPane(messages)
               contents += outputTextScrollPane
            }
        }
```

So I would love to have something like outputTextScrollPane.goBottom() to make it go to the bottom automatically..
Thanks in advance !

Comment: why don't you try out your code before you post a question here? What you have above won't compile. And you'll probably find that the behaviour you want is the default behaviour.

Comment: That's not the complete code if you want I can put the complete one..